# API do Facebook - Puxando posts com HashTag

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Estou tendo que aplicar a API do facebook em um site, puxando os posts de uma pagina, gostaria de saber, se tem alguma maneira de puxar somente posts contendo uma HashTag, a API permite isso?

**COMO ESTOU PUXANDO**

que no caso, poderia ser visto em funcionamento através desse link:

> https://graph.facebook.com/*********/posts?access_token=*************&fields=message,full_picture,link

```
function fbFeed(){

     var pagina = "***********";
     var token = "************";
     var campos = "fields=message,full_picture,link";
     var limite = "4"

     var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+pagina+"/posts?" +
               "access_token="+token+"" +
               "&limit="+limite+"&"+campos+"&callback=?";
```

Comment: Você é ADM da página que deseja puxar os dados?

Comment: Sim, já estou conseguindo puxar todos os posts, mas gostaria de somente puxar os posts que contem tal hashtag

Comment: Chuto que se tiver será alguma operação com FQL, apesar de eu nunca ter feito esse filtro. Porém, se não tiver uma forma direta, você pode usar o `filter` do javacript para filtrar somente os posts com a tal hashtag.

Comment: Poste como está puxando os posts, será mais fácil para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar o post, colocando como estou fazendo!

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível...

[Facebook is Shutting Down Access to Hashtags in its API](https://thenextweb.com/facebook/2015/04/03/facebook-might-be-shutting-down-access-to-hashtags-in-its-api/#.tnw_JR2M2Eck) (Abril de 2015)

O explorer já nem funciona para fazer o search das hashtags, como sugerido aqui: [Facebook API search for hashtag - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034754/facebook-api-search-for-hashtag).

E isso tudo era para fazer busca genérica pela hashtag. Na documentação oficial para pesquisa das informações de uma página especifica não consta nada a respeito de hashtags: [Page - Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/)